# MySQL update if value is greater than that current value

Tags: mysql

I'm going to go ahead and post my scary MySQL code:

```
INSERT INTO monthlystats (id, server, time, uptime, players, rank) 
VALUES (09126, 6, 0912, 302, 0, 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uptime = if(302 > uptime, 302, uptime), if(0 > players, 0, players), if(1 > rank, 1, rank)
```

Ok, so let me explain what I'm TRYING to do.

1. "id" has a unique index. If that index doesn't already exist, I want to insert those values.
2. If there's a duplicate key, I want to instead UPDATE each of 3 fields, only IF the new values are greater than the ones currently in the table.

It looks like I'm doing something terribly wrong, and I quite frankly have NO idea what to do. I tried making it good, but it turned out to be a horrible mess.

I hope that somebody can lead me in the right direction, and help me learn (and anyone else that is trying to learn) how to do things like this. Thank you.

Comment: So you did that well for `uptime`, repeat it for `players` and `rank` and it should work

Comment: Oops. one moment. I see what you're talking about, but i don't think that's the actual problem. Edit: oh my gosh, that was the problem! Go ahead and make an answer.

Comment: and what is the actual problem? I don't see any in the question

Comment: @zerkms I had `uptime = if(302 > uptime, 302, uptime)` but for players and rank, I left off the `whatever =` part of it, and just had an if. ._.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your query seems fine but you could improve it for clarity:

```
INSERT INTO monthlystats (id, server, time, uptime, players, rank) 
  VALUES (09126, 6, 0912, 302, 0, 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  uptime = GREATEST(uptime, VALUES(uptime)), 
  players = GREATEST(players, VALUES(players)),
  rank = GREATEST(rank, VALUES(rank))
```

Answer (score 6):

You could avoid a bit of duplication using [VALUES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function. And other things are just good in your query

```
INSERT INTO monthlystats (id, server, time, uptime, players, rank) 
VALUES (09126, 6, 0912, 302, 0, 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uptime = if(VALUES(uptime) > uptime, VALUES(uptime), uptime)
```

Comment: I don't know how I overlooked something like that. What a typo >.>
Anyway, thank you for spotting that! I probably would've never figured it out. And it makes me feel good that I almost had it right. :)

Comment: This is the better solution because it allows to update multiple values depending on ONE column.