# MySQL update if value is greater than current value

Tags: mysql

Here is my insertion scripts:

```
INSERT INTO CONTENT (content_id, version, description)
VALUES ('123', '1', 'This is an example')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE version=VALUES(version),description=VALUES(description)
```

`content_id` is pk.
If there is a duplicate key, I want to check the value under `version`. If it is greater than that I want to insert, then ignore the new insertion. Otherwise, update the one with `content_id` in db. I tried to search my question first on stack overflow and found this:[MySQL update if value is greater than that current value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081481/mysql-update-if-value-is-greater-than-that-current-value#10081527). But it doesn't solve my case.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT INTO CONTENT (content_id, version, description)
VALUES ('123', '1', 'This is an example')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE version=
    CASE WHEN VALUES(version) > version THEN VALUES(version) ELSE version END,
description=
    CASE WHEN VALUES(version) > version THEN VALUES(description) ELSE description END`